# Haskell IO Int and Int

Tags: haskell, types, monads, io-monad

I recently started to learn Haskell. I'm trying to write a program that pick a random element of array:

```
import System.Random

randomInt :: (Int, Int) -> IO Int
randomInt range = randomRIO range :: IO Int

choseRandom :: [a] -> a
choseRandom list = 
    length list
    >>=
        (\l -> randomInt(0,l-1))
        >>=
            (\num -> (list !! num))

main :: IO ()
main = undefined
```

and I get the following error:

```
Build FAILED

C:\Users\User\Haskell\Real\src\Main.hs: line 7, column 9:
  Couldn't match expected type `IO Int' with actual type `Int'

    In the return type of a call of `length'

    In the first argument of `(>>=)', namely `length list'

    In the first argument of `(>>=)', namely

      `length list >>= (\ l -> randomInt (0, l - 1))'
```

what I'm doing wrong? It's hard for me to deal monads for first times

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using IO inside `choseRandom` you need to change the type signature:

```
choseRandom :: [a] -> IO a
```

secondly, you don't need to use `>>=` to get the length of the list. `>>=` has type

```
Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

The type of `length` is `[a] -> Int`, so the type of `length list` is `Int`, which is not a monad.

You can calculate it directly when calling `randomInt`:

```
choseRandom :: [a] -> IO a
choseRandom list = 
    randomInt(0, length list) >>= (\num -> return (list !! num))
```

which is the same as

```
choseRandom :: [a] -> IO a
choseRandom list = fmap (\num -> (list !! num)) (randomInt(0, length list))
```

Comment: The ugly `(\num -> (list !! num))` could be shortened to `(list !!)` once he got the `fmap` idea.

Answer (score 7):

> It's hard for me to deal monads for first times

Yes, and you make it harder by avoiding syntactic support. Just write it thus:

```
choseRandom list = do
   let l = length list
   num <- randomInt(0,l-1)
   return (list !! num)
```

Doesn't this look much better?

Now to the point: the `randomRIO` function, as their type indicates, uses some global state (probably the system timer). Hence you can use results from `RandomRIO` only in the `IO` Monad.

An alternative would be to initialize a random generator in the `main` function, and pass this generator down to pure functions that need "random" values.

Comment: It's not the system timer, but a shared mutable variable with content of type `StdGen`, the same kind of generator which the pure functions in the library pass around explicitly. The IO-based random number functions essentially just wrap reading and writing to that variable around the pure functions.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
import System.Random

randomInt :: (Int, Int) -> IO Int
randomInt range = randomRIO range :: IO Int

choseRandom :: [b] -> IO b
choseRandom list = randomInt (0, length list) >>= \x -> return $ list !! x
```

I find this more idiomatic:

```
choseRandom list = do
 a <- randomInt (0, length list)
 return $ list !! a
```

The problem with your choseRandom function is that the type signature is wrong there. The type of `>>=` should be `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, so you should wrap the result back in the monad using `return`.

So it operates something like this:

`randomInt (0, length list)` will give you `IO Int` and using the `>>=` function you will  extract out the `Int` from that. Now you can extract out the corresponding element from the list using `!!` function. But since the output type should be `m b` you shoud wrap it back in monad using `return`.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you need to fix the type signature fo `choseRandom`.  Secondly I think you'll find this much easier if you use `do` notation.

```
choseRandom :: [a] -> IO a
choseRandom list = do
  let l = length list
  num <- randomInt (0, l-1)
  return (list !! num)
```

Comment: For someone who is learning about monads, I would avoid using the do notation at first

Answer (score 0):

```
choseRandom :: [a] -> IO a
choseRandom xs = (xs !!) <$> randomRIO (0, length xs - 1)
```